# How to grant AWS Lambda access to Aurora serverless database (SG rules not working)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I am trying to give a Lambda function access to an Aurora Serverless v2 database.

I have been able to **whitelist my own local IP addresses** in the security group rules and connect to the server locally (it's a public instance). All the code contained in the Lambda function I can execute successfully locally (inserting a row into a table on the database).

I've **created a security group for the Lambda function**, and **another for the RDS instance**. I've **whitelisted the Lambda function's security group in inbound rules** for the RDS SG, and similar in **the outbound rules in the other direction, in the Lambda function's security group**.

**My current security groups:**

[Security groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqT0x.png)

**The inbound rules for fs-secg-1 (RDS security group):**

[Aurora serverless v2 inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfGvI.png)

**Outbound rules for the fs-lambda-1 (Lambda security group):**

[Lambda outbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHezb.png)

**The Lambda function configuration:**

[Lambda configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzIcF.png)

However, I still cannot connect to the RDS instance from Lambda - my function quietly times out. All the advice I can find online points to the above (create two security groups to allow the connection).

I'm also not sure how to debug the timeout, as there is no stack-trace in the Lambda logs.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to show your user role details for lambda? Are you sure resources ids are correct?

Comment: How is your Lambda function attempting to connect? DNS name, private IP, public IP?

Comment: @CharithJ I can add a screenshot if it helps. The policies I have attached to the Lambda are AmazonEC2FullAccess, AmazonS3FullAccess, AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole - is that what you mean? I attached these via the console.

Comment: @jarmod Hey - attempting to connect with the DNS name. This connects successfully from my local address after whitelisting my local IPs.

Comment: @GasconPardieu: Those do not provide access to Aurora. Have you tried giving full access to Aurora (Just for testing purpose you give try with full access). Hope your lambda is connecting through private IPs? 
This may help : https://awsauroralabsmy.com/serverless/dataapi/

Comment: @CharithJ Ok, I've just added AmazonRDSFullAccess (there is no equivalent for Aurora, but they are essentially the same managed service). However, the result is the same, timed-out connection.

Comment: @CharithJ Thanks for the link. The problem is that Aurora is now only available on serverless v2. But serverless v2 does not have the data API option. Serverless v1 is deprecated.

Comment: Have you specified resources properly. YOu can try with all "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]

Comment: @CharithJ The Lambda was actually generated by Chalice (I added VPC security groups and subnets manually). The role policy is auto-generated by Chalice. Resource is specified like this: "Resource": "arn:*:logs:*:*:*"

Comment: @GasconPardieu: That would give permission only for logs. Not for rds? You can try with "*" if that makes any difference

Comment: @CharithJ For the AmazonRDSFullAccess policy attached, it's specified already like this: "Resource": "*"

Comment: what subnet is your lambda in compared to the subnet of your database, is thee a network route between the two? If your lambda is in a private subnet, does it have a route to the DB subnet or a NAT gateway? 

it's a better test to spin up an EC2 instance on the same subnet as the lambda and see if you can connect there (instead of trying trying to testing locally as this is a different route than what your lambda is trying).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JDD I have three subnets. The Lambda function is in all three of them, and the RDS instance is in one of them - does that make sense? I've added some screenshots to illustrate.